# How do I retrieve an "string" inside a List<string> stringName's ArrayList?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, arraylist

I'm quite new to C# and I'm currently faced with 1 issue while attempting to retrieve a "data" of **object** type during **runtime** of the program since this "data" is received from an EEG device and streamed into the Unity3D platform. This specific "data" inside the **object** received is then required to vary an gameObject (using Unity3D).

However, from the list of Unity-Emotiv API that the **Emotiv** provides, it seems that this string "data" is stored into a `List<string> _streams` denoted below:

```
public List<string> GetStreamsList()
{
List<string> _streams = new List<string>();
if(EEGToggle.isOn)
 {_streams.Add("eeg"); //Add 'eeg' obj }
if(PMToggle.isOn)
_streams.Add("met"); // Adds 'met' obj, the Main object that I want to access and retrieve specific data
if(POWToggle.isOn)
{_streams.Add("pow);} //adds 'pow' obj
...//many other object subscription that one can add/subscribe to
return _streams;
}
```

Reference:
https://github.com/Emotiv/cortex-v2-example/blob/master/unity/Assets/SimpleExample.cs

However, in each of the individual subscriptions/adding of string, each contains their relevant object which are sent from the EEG Headset to Unity.

ie: `"met": [false,null,false,null,null,false,null,true,0.266589,false,null,true,0.098421]`

`"pow":[0.225,0.213,0.537,0.19,0.34, 0.511,0.808,1.706,0.839,0.416, ... 0.92,0.469,1.657,1.443,0.912, 2.675,0.824,0.951,0.303,0.881 ]`
and many more, depending on the number of subscription added and they are sent as separate obj to the Unity environment.

Some insights on the `met` example provided: The `true/false` denotes the connectivity between labels of the EEG headset and human scalp (whether it's able to be detected and being able to send data) while the values `(null/ 0.xxxx)` denotes the data that is picked up when it is `true (connected)`.

As I'm focusing on the `met`, we can safely ignore the example on `pow`.
According to the Documentation, `foc.isActive, value` is indexed at the last 2, and since my primary focus is on the last 2 indexes of the `met` object , we can safely ignore the front. But since there will be a need to reference to this `obj` data received, I would like to query on a way to `retrieve this focus numeric data at the last index constantly during runtime` then converting its `object` class to a `float variable` as this last index value is required to vary an gameObject as mentioned in the 1st paragraph?

Add-on: Emotiv Unity Plugin.

Comment: I'm not following: The `_streams.Add("")`-calls does what with an ArrayList?

Comment: `inside this _streams.Add("met"), there contains an ArrayList` .. no it doesn't .. t least at this stage of the code you show it is a simple `List<string>` where you added only an element `"met"` ... Could you provide some more context about the types you are actually receiving, not where items are added to the list of strings but what you actually get back? It sounds like you rather get an array of arbitrary `object` you would like to parse ...

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, let me try to answer them one by one.
@Seth, this `_streams.Add("")` adds the pre-coded utility that the Emotiv API has provided in the case whereby a "Subscribe" (or Add/Monitor) happens to the `List<string> XXX`. 

Then the List `_streams` adds this specific 'Subscription' say `met` in this case. Inside this `met`, it contains a list of items (I supposed) and it prints out the example I provided above. However, it is still able to add other 'Subscription' if required to that `_streams` list.

Comment: @derHugo, based on the Emotiv API documentation, they stated that within the `met`, the contains additional `labels` (which they called) that contains the `boolean` and `number` associated to each of the 'labels'. for example. `bool label1, label1 num, ...` so on so forth. It is from the provided sample output that I'm assuming that they are all strings.

Comment: This information is of `object` type, not `string`.

Comment: So how exactly do you get those? In what type/format? This `"met": [false,null,false,null,null,false,null,true,0.266589,false,null,true,0.098421]` would look like a JSON string to me ... in general for `string` -> `float` see [`float.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.tryparse)

Comment: @KiynL thanks for the correcting.

@derHugo, my apologies the `"met": [false,null,false,null,null,false,null,true,0.266589,false,null,true,0.098421]` is of object type.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of language on this question makes it difficult to answer.
What I've derived from you question is that you're looking for a way to find the last item in the list and type check it or try to cast it. I might have misunderstood the question.

The following is just and idea and should be expanded by your own thoughts. I would suggest putting something like this in a function and calling it recursively.

```
        string lastItemInList = string.Empty;
        var list = new List<string>();
        if(list.Count > 0)
            lastItemInList = list.Last();

        bool boolResult;
        var isBool = bool.TryParse(lastItemInList, out boolResult);

        if(isBool) // denotes the connectivity between some metrics to the API
        {
            if (boolResult) // I assume 'true' means you're connected
            {
                // connected, so there might be new data in the list. Recursively call this function to get the next value and run the logic against it.
            }
            else // its false, you're not connected
            {
                // retry connectivity
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // it's not a bool. So it could be "data that is picked up when it is true (connected)"
            if(lastItemInList != null) // cast it to float and do what you want with float
            {
                float floatResult;
                var isFloat = float.TryParse(lastItemInList, out floatResult);
                if (isFloat)
                {
                    // do what you need to do with the float value
                }
                //Note, there could be a else condition here if the data is a anomaly
            }
            else
            {
                // it's null, so you do nothing I assume
            }
        }
```

Note, when calling it recursively, just make sure to add limited try logic with a wait, to stop retrying if the connectivity results to false several time in a row.

Storing data in a unstructured list is not the best approach. I would suggest utilizing the object orientated power of C# and better parse your data if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response, I've edited some minor class type from the received data of the EEG device to `object` type in the query brought up.

Comment: I see, safely casting object to float can be done by using 'float.TryParse(theObject, out theCastedFloatValue)'. This function also returns a bool value that indicates if the cast was successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete guide on how to read a list of objects.

```cs
private List<object> _streams = new List<object>();
private void Start()
{
    _streams = new List<object>() {null, 25f, new GameObject(), "XS"};
    foreach (var stream in _streams)
    {
        if (stream == null) continue; // for ignoring null

        if (stream is string _s) // String Type 
        {
            Debug.Log(_s);
        }
        else if (stream is float _f) // Float Type
        {
            SetVariable(_f); //...
        }
        else if (stream is bool _b) // Boolean Type
        {
            SetLightTurn(_b); //...
        }
        else if (stream is GameObject _g) // Game Object Type
        {
            _g.SetActive(false);
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Pertaining to this, can I check if it is indeed an object? 
Because based on an example that the Emotiv Team provided https://github.com/Emotiv/cortex-v2-example/blob/master/unity/Assets/SimpleExample.cs here, they made used of `string` as well. It is only after adding these `strings`, can the `object` be send to the unity platform.

Comment: @Jun The string itself should also be included in the object, and if something is not an object, it will not be included in this list. But in general, this method of reading the list can cover any class and maximizes your control, which is 100% better than the parsing method.

Comment: but is this only applicable if the string object only contains 1 string? Because in my case, my string object contains several object and I would only want to access 1 of the object sent amongst many to only retrieve 1 specific float during runtime (? the documentation only provided it as number, so I assumed it to be float since there's decimal places). Also, the string object of interest is only sent every 10 seconds.